# JAVA-JDBC 'Numeric Overflow' while writing the oracle table to file

Tags: java, jdbc

I have below code to write oracle db values to a csv file. the prining working fine for small set of data but showing below error with large set of data

```
Error: Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01426: numeric overflow
```

I am using below code for printing the table to CSV

```
//creating PreparedStatement object to execute query
        PreparedStatement preStatement;
        preStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        ResultSet result = preStatement.executeQuery();
        ResultSetMetaData rmsd = result.getMetaData();
        int Columncount = rmsd.getColumnCount();

//Get the column name and print the column name
        for (int iterator=1; iterator<= Columncount; iterator++) 
        {
            fw.append(rmsd.getColumnName(iterator)+",");
        }
        fw.append(LINE_SEP); //goto next line

//Print the data into excel using iteration
        while(result.next()){
            try {
                for (int jterator=1; jterator<=Columncount; jterator++){
                    fw.append(result.getString(jterator));
                    fw.append(',');
                }
                fw.append(LINE_SEP);

            } catch (SQLException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            fw.flush();
            fw.flush();
        }
        System.out.println("Data is successfully written to "+conn.fileName);
        fw.close();
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.I have also checked the Column Type and ColumnClass for the query I used and updated below

```
Column 1 Type = 12 &     ColClass = java.lang.String
Column 2 Type = 12 &     ColClass = java.lang.String
Column 3 Type = 12 &     ColClass = java.lang.String
Column 4 Type = 12 &     ColClass = java.lang.String
Column 5 Type = 93 &     ColClass = java.sql.Timestamp
Column 6 Type = 93 &     ColClass = java.sql.Timestamp
Column 7 Type = 2  &     ColClass = java.math.BigDecimal
Column 8 Type = 2  &     ColClass = java.math.BigDecimal
```

Comment: What does your query look like ?

Comment: To get that error, you must be doing some math in the query, so perhaps if you show us the query, we could help you figure out what to change. The Java code you've shown cannot cause this to happen. It's the SQL query that we need to see, and we might need to know the datatypes of the columns being queried too.

Comment: Updated the Column Type and Column Class for the query. Is that what you guys were looking for.

Comment: No it isn't.  They are asking for the SQL that you are executing; i.e. what is in the `sql` variable ....